# Draw a line of the average point values R

Tags: r, graph, average

[image]
I am trying to plot a graph where you can see Customer Ratings as Dots and a line which shows the average customer ratings, but I cant figure out how to create a line which gives the average. I am a beginner with the R language btw. ;)

```
dataset = read.csv("MOCK_DATA3.csv")

beoorGraph <- dataset %>%
  mutate(Maand = factor(Maand, levels = c("November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April")))


beoorGraph <- ggplot(beoorGraph, aes(x= Maand, y=Klanttevredenheid))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title="Klanttevredenheid")

beoorGraph
```

I've tried
stat_summary()
geom_hline()
and other things, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Why does it not work? Is there an error thrown? How does the output deviate from your expectation?

Comment: Well whenever I use geom_hline() it gives the following error: Error in mean(y) : object 'y' not found. The graph itself work fine, but whatever I try I cant seem to get a line that displays the average of all points. ``beoorGraph <- dataset %>%

  mutate(Maand = factor(Maand, levels = c("November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April")))

beoorGraph <- ggplot(beoorGraph, aes(x= Maand, y=Klanttevredenheid))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(y),color="red")
  labs(title="Klanttevredenheid")``

Comment: It is usually best to provide a minimally reproducible dataset. Run `dput` on `dataset` and then paste the output into your question so people can help easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `geom_point()`, you might have to summarise your data first, e.g. with:

```r
beoorGraph <- dataset %>%
  mutate(Maand = factor(Maand, levels = c("November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April"))) %>%
  group_by(Maand) %>%
  summarise(Klanttevredenheid = mean(Klanttevredenheid))
```

Comment: Whenever I implement the group and summarise it it gives an error: Error in group_by(Maand) : object 'Maand' not found!